# How can i join with a derived table?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.1

The sql statement is like this:

```
select posts.id, posts.title 
from posts 
inner join (select distinct post_id,created_at  
            from comments 
            order by created_at DESC limit 5
            ) as foo 
        on posts.id=foo.post_id 
order by foo.created_at DESC;
```

I want to get a rails 3 sql statement equivalent to the above one.

What i tried is given below:

The following sql query gives similar result.

```
select distinct post_id, created_at  
from comments 
order by created_at DESC limit 5

@temp = Comment.select('distinct(comments.post_id),created_at').order('created_at DESC').limit(5)
```

I tried to join this derived @temp table with posts table to get the posts.title

I tried this but  failed.

```
@temp2 = @temp.joins('posts')
```

So, How can i join posts table with derived @temp table ?

```
                                   Table "public.posts"
   Column    |          Type          |                     Modifiers                      
-------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer                | not null default nextval('posts_id_seq'::regclass)
 title       | character varying(100) | not null
 content     | character varying(500) | not null
 created_at  | date                   | 
 updated_at  | date                   | 
 tags        | character varying(55)  | not null default '50'::character varying
 category_id | integer                | not null default 1
Indexes:
    "posts_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

comments

```
                                   Table "public.comments"
   Column   |          Type          |                       Modifiers                       
------------+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer                | not null default nextval('comments_id_seq'::regclass)
 post_id    | integer                | not null
 name       | character varying(255) | not null
 email      | character varying(255) | not null
 content    | character varying(500) | not null
 created_at | date                   | 
 updated_at | date                   | 
Indexes:
    "comments_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

posts model, `has_many :comments`, comments model, `belongs_to :post`

Comment: Isn't there any option without using find_by_sql in rails 3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question author needs to read up on basic Rails and activerecord usage before jumping into SQL.  Need to understand how Activerecord models your data and how to use it.  First figure out what you want to do in common language and then see how you can use what exists to do it.

Rails does not know the structure of your @temp table.  It only has a result set and from what I understand, AREL does not build logic from the result set.  It builds from schemas which it pulls for active record models.

You cannot build a view from this data, so your only option is to use the standard join options with activerecord classes or to do custom sql.

In Rails 3, the ActiveRecord relational algebra is very advanced and has made queries very easy.

`Comment.order("#{Comment.table_name}.created_at desc').limit(5).joins(:posts).order("#{Post.table_name} created_at desc")`

Comment: Then how can i join with the derived table? Can you post the rails way sql statement?

Comment: I don't understand your whole model structure.  Is it just posts with comments?  Do you have the has_many, belongs_to properly setup?  It seems you should not have to do the joins yourself. Did you check the rails join documentation if you have to?  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: I have updated the original post/question. See again to understand.

Comment: I have updated the original post/question. See again to understand. I'm trying to get a rails 3 sql statement equivalent to this=> `select posts.id, posts.title 
from posts 
inner join (select distinct post_id,created_at  
            from comments 
            order by created_at DESC limit 5
            ) as foo 
        on posts.id=foo.post_id 
order by foo.created_at DESC;`

Comment: I meant what do you want from your rails objects?  Please explain in english, not SQL what you are trying to achieve.  The posts of the most recent comments with most recent first?   If so then did you try the rails methods?  Rails 3 has a lot of magic.  `Comment.order('comments.created_at desc').limit(5).join(:posts).order('posts created_at desc')`  You can check the SQL by watching the console or put a `.to_sql` at the end.  Basically Rails 3 has made it too easy.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5673/discussion-between-amala-and-guru)

Comment: I got error http://pastebin.com/8sdx49Qg , for this `Comment.order('comments.created_at desc').limit(5).join(:posts).order('posts created_at desc')`

Comment: You did join instead of joins.  join is the function for arrays, joins is for active record.  my comment above was wrong

Comment: @Amala re: "AREL does not build logic from the result set. It builds from schemas which it pulls for active record models", could you point me in the right direction towards what file would need to be monkey-patched to make it create methods from a result set for a derived table?  Is the obstacle that it can't change the set of available methods at run-time?