# Can anyone post the equivalent rails 3 sql statement of this?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby on Rails: How can i join with a derived table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403205/ruby-on-rails-how-can-i-join-with-a-derived-table)

posts table

```
                                   Table "public.posts"
   Column    |          Type          |                     Modifiers                      
-------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer                | not null default nextval('posts_id_seq'::regclass)
 title       | character varying(100) | not null
 content     | character varying(500) | not null
 created_at  | date                   | 
 updated_at  | date                   | 
 tags        | character varying(55)  | not null default '50'::character varying
 category_id | integer                | not null default 1
Indexes:
    "posts_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

comments table

```
                                   Table "public.comments"
   Column   |          Type          |                       Modifiers                       
------------+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer                | not null default nextval('comments_id_seq'::regclass)
 post_id    | integer                | not null
 name       | character varying(255) | not null
 email      | character varying(255) | not null
 content    | character varying(500) | not null
 created_at | date                   | 
 updated_at | date                   | 
Indexes:
    "comments_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

I'm trying to make a equivalent rails 3 sql statement of this.

```
select posts.id, posts.title 
from posts 
inner join (select distinct post_id,created_at  
            from comments 
            order by created_at DESC limit 5
            ) as foo 
        on posts.id=foo.post_id 
order by foo.created_at DESC;
```

It's to get recent commented-post (limit 5). It's a complex sql query. Need to select posts.title from posts table joining comments table.

Comment: What's wrong with `find_by_sql`?

Comment: I know find_by_sql works, but i'm looking for the rails 3 sql statement for complex sql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails3 way to do a query like that is `find_by_sql`:

```
posts = Post.find_by_sql(%q{
    select posts.id, posts.title 
    from posts 
    inner join (select distinct post_id,created_at  
                from comments 
                order by created_at DESC limit 5
                ) as foo 
            on posts.id=foo.post_id 
    order by foo.created_at DESC
})
```

You could use `joins` if you wanted but, IMHO, that would just obfuscate things:

```
Post.select('posts.id, posts.title').
     joins('join (select distinct post_id, created_at from comments order by created_at desc limit 5) as foo on posts.id = foo.post_id').
     order('foo.created_at desc')
```

Or perhaps something even more complicated like this:

```
join_to = Comment.select('distinct post_id, created_at').
                  order('created_at desc').
                  limit(5).
                  to_sql

posts = Post.select('posts.id, posts.title').
             joins("join (#{join_to}) as foo on posts.id = foo.post_id").
             order('foo.created_at desc')
```

Some things are just easier and clearer in SQL than AREL. The [`find_by_sql` method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#finding-by-sql) exists for a reason:

> `find_by_sql` provides you with a simple way of making custom calls to the database and retrieving instantiated objects.

and this sort of thing is exactly what `find_by_sql` is for. You'll have to pull out `find_by_sql` for a lot of advanced SQL features (such as CTEs) and there's no reason to be afraid of it or avoid it: ActiveRecord is a tool, not a dogmatic way of life. `find_by_sql` does have downsides (such as not playing that nicely with scopes) but so does the standard AREL stuff (such as not playing nicely with non-trivial SQL).

Comment: `Posts.select('posts.id, posts.title').
      joins('join (select distinct post_id, ...) as foo on posts.id = foo.post_id').
      order('foo.created_at desc')` , It will be Post.select, and complete this line, `select distinct post_id, ...`

Comment: @guru: Thanks for spotting the typo. I figured the ellipses would be clear but I replaced them to avoid confusion.